ResourceExhaustedError problem with efficientnet in keras
During my training, I encountered the ResourceExhaustedError error. I want to know what I did wrong in my code or what can be improved.
error message(I have omitted some of the error code)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ResourceExhaustedError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_13600\817967598.py in <module>
      3                    steps_per_epoch=len(train_generator),
      4                    validation_data=valid_generator,
----> 5                    validation_steps=len(valid_generator))
      6 
...

sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()
conv_base1 = tf.keras.applications.EfficientNetB3(weights='imagenet',include_top=False , input_shape=(300,300,3))
conv_base1.trainable = True
conv_base1._name = 'conv_base1'

conv_base2 = tf.keras.applications.EfficientNetB3(weights='imagenet',include_top=False , input_shape=(300,300,3))
conv_base2.trainable = True
conv_base2._name = 'conv_base2'

conv_base3 = tf.keras.applications.EfficientNetB3(weights='imagenet',include_top=False , input_shape=(300,300,3))
conv_base3.trainable = True
conv_base3._name = 'conv_base3'

input_image1 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(300, 300, 3))
input_image2 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(300, 300, 3))
input_image3 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(300, 300, 3))

x_img1 = conv_base1(input_image1)
x_img2 = conv_base2(input_image2)
x_img3 = conv_base3(input_image3)

x_img1 = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x_img1)
x_img2 = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x_img2)
x_img3 = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x_img3)

x = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([x_img2, x_img2, x_img3])
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='softmax')(x)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input_image1 , input_image2 , input_image3], outputs=x)
model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.000001), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(train_generator,
                   epochs=num_epochs, verbose=1,
                   steps_per_epoch=len(train_generator),
                   validation_data=valid_generator,
                   validation_steps=len(valid_generator))

In my model, I will input three (300, 300, 3) images at a time and concatenate them. This can be used normally in InceptionResnetV2, but the ResourceExhaustedError problem will occur when using EfficientNetB3.
I have adjusted the batch_size=1, and I tried to set some layer trainable=False but result very bad, my GPU is RTX3060ti.

hi @Pepeeeee  The ResourceExhaustedError typically occurs when TensorFlow runs out of available resources during the execution of your model. This error is commonly encountered when working with large models or datasets, especially when training on GPU.Decrease the batch size further. You've already tried setting batch_size=1, but you can try reducing it even more.
